# Por que consigo dar argumentos para uma função escrita depois no programa?

Tags: python, funções, parâmetros, argumento

> Estou fazendo recentemente um curso de python e me foi apresentado a
> seguinte linha de código:

```
def main():
     name = input("What's your name?")
     hello(name)

def hello(to="world"):
     print("Hello",to)


main()
```

> Eu não consigo entender como que na primeira função eu consigo passar um parâmetro para uma função que nem ao menos foi criada...

Comment: Não passou nada antes dela ser criada. Você "chamou" o main() só na ultima linha. Nesse momento já existia a `hello`

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> *A function definition is an executable statement. Its execution binds the function name in the current local namespace to a function object*
> *...*
> *The function definition does not execute the function body; this gets executed only when the function is called.*

Traduzindo:

> *A definição de uma função é uma declaração executável. Sua execução associa o nome da função no *namespace* atual ao objeto que representa a função.*
> *...*
> *A definição de uma função não executa o seu corpo; este só é executado quando a função é chamada.*

Ou seja, quando você **define** uma função (`def nome_funcao(etc...`), o código que está dentro dela não é executado. Você só está associando o nome da função ao respectivo bloco de código. Mas como aquele bloco não é executado, não dá erro (ou seja, ao definir a função `main`, o código dela não é executado, então ele não verifica neste momento se a função `hello` existe ou não).

Quando você chama a função, aí o código dentro dela é executado. Ou seja, ao executar `main()`, em determinado momento ele vai tentar chamar a função `hello`. E como `hello` foi definida **antes** de você chamar `main`, então tudo bem.

---

O mesmo não ocorreria se você chamasse `main` antes de definir `hello`, pois aí dá erro:

```py
def main():
     name = input("What's your name?")
     hello(name)

# chamei main() antes de definir hello
main() # erro! NameError

def hello(to="world"):
     print("Hello",to)
```

Agora dará erro: "*NameError: name 'hello' is not defined*", pois o código de `main` foi executado e tentou chamar `hello`, que ainda não foi definida.

---

Podemos ver melhor este comportamento com esta função:

```py
def funcao():
    funcao_que_nao_existe(x)
    outra_funcao_que_nao_existe(y, z)
```

Se meu arquivo `.py` tiver somente isso, não dá erro. Isso porque, como já dito, só estou definindo a função (ou seja, associando o nome `funcao` com o respectivo bloco de código). Mas o código dentro da função não é executado, por isso ele não vai detectar que as duas funções ali não existem.

Só quando eu chamar a função é que dá erro:

```py
def funcao():
    funcao_que_nao_existe(x)
    outra_funcao_que_nao_existe(y, z)

funcao() # NameError: name 'funcao_que_nao_existe' is not defined
```

Pois agora ele tentará executar o código da função, e verá que a `funcao_que_nao_existe` não existe, porque não foi definida em lugar nenhum.